# Handle column accessed and changed from two or more connections (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, ebean

I need your advice.
I have a mysql database which stores the data from my minecraft server. The server is using the ebean api for the mysql stuff.

I will have multiple servers running the same synched data when the user base increases. The server that the user is connected to does not matter. It looks all the same for him. But how can I handle an example case in which from two servers two players in the same guild edit something at the same time. One server will throw an optimistic lock exception. But what to do if it is something important like a donation to the guild bank? The amount donated might get duped or is lost. Tell the user to retry it? Or let the server automatically resend the query with the updated data from the database? A friend of mine said something like a socket server in the middle that handles ALL mysql statements might be a good idea. But that would require a lot of work to make sure that it does reconnect to the minecraft servers if the connection is lost etc. It would also require me to get the raw update query or serialize the ebean table but I don't know how to accomplish any of those possibilities.

---

I have not found an answer to my question yet and I hope that it hasn't been answered before.

Comment: When understand your problem. You have more Minecraft server and one database server with multiple schemas for each server one. Is this OK ?
The you can make a new common schema like master or so with all uniqe tables and in each minecraft schema you build a view for this table that access the master table. So each gets the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different kinds of operations the Minecraft servers can perform on the DBMS. On one hand, you have state-update operations, like making a deposit to an account. The history of these operations matters. For the sake of integrity, you must use transactions for these. They're not *idempotent*, meaning that you can't repeat them multiple times and expect the same result as if you only did them once. You should investigate the use of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` transactions for these.

If something fails during such a transaction, you must issue a `ROLLBACK` of the transaction and try again. You'd be smart to log these retries in case you get a lot of rollbacks: that suggests you have some sort of concurrency trouble to track down.

By the way, you don't need to bother with an explicit transaction on a query like

```
UPDATE credit SET balance = balance + 200 WHERE account  = 12367
```

Your DBMS will get this right, even when multiple connections hit the same account number.

The other kind of operation is idempotent. That is, if you carry out the operation more than once, the result is the same as if you did it once. For example, setting the name of a player is idempotent. For those operations, if you get some kind of exception, you can either repeat the operation, or simply ignore the failure in the assumption that the operation will be repeated later in the normal sequence of gameplay.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. It helped me a lot. Do you know how to solve this problem with the ebean api, without using raw queries? Currently I'm using the table instance with for example databaseInstance.save/update(tableInstance);

Comment: Because ebean currently for example creates queries like     UPDATE credit SET balance = 200 WHERE account  = 12367 AND version = 12

Comment: Sorry to say, I am ignorant of ebean. But it appears (http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/transactions) to provide both automatic and programmer-specified support for DBMS transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if there is any kind of special word for the "relative" change of columns i.e. "balance + 200" so I can look up how to solve this with ebean? Or do you have a link for that also? Thank you very much again for your hard work :)